# What is the definition of function of bounded variation over the whole interval $(-\infty, +\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is the definition of real-valued function of bounded variation over the whole interval $(-\infty, +\infty)$? I know one [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_one_variable) of functions of bounded variation, but the interval here is $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$. How to set a partition of $(-\infty, +\infty)$? $\{-\infty=x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n=+\infty\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a function. For each $x\in \Bbb R$ define $$T_F(x):=\sup\biggl\{\sum_{j=1}^n|F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})|\biggm\vert n\in \Bbb N ,-\infty<x_0<\cdots<x_n=x\biggr\}.$$ The function $T_F$ is increasing with values in $[0,\infty]$. So the limit $T_F(\infty):=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} T_F(x)$ exists. If this limit is finite then we say $F$ is of bounded variation on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: This isn't a natural definition, since, with this, even something like $f(x) = x$ would fail to have bounded variation. We want the notion of bounded variation to capture "well-behavedness"  in some sense, and certainly the identity function is well-behaved.

Comment: Note one thing, book like Real analysis modern techniques written by Folland follows this definition. Actually this definition is an extended version of the definition of bounded variation in compact interval. Another fact is that, for a Lebesgue integrable function $f$ on real line the function $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$ satisfies the condition given in definition, as we do for a Lebesgue integrable function in compact interval.